# Title missing in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biber, compiling with xelatex.

I have an issue with some references (@inproceedings): they appear in the bibliography, but without the title. Here is my header.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-biochem]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{d:/bib/my_bib.bib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
```

Here is one of the faulty references

```
@inproceedings{beziat_launay_typo_Metrans_2015,
title = {A Comprehensive View of Goods Transport Systems. Typology and Analysis of Delivery Tours in the Paris Region},
author = {Beziat, Adrien and Launay, Pierre and Toilier, Florence},
booktitle = {6th Metrans International Urban Freight Conference},
address = {Long Beach, CA, USA},
year = {2015}
}
```

and here is what I obtain:
[image: screenshot]

If you have a suggestion, I'd very grateful! Thanks in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be by design. The `inproceedings` driver does not print the title in the `chem-biochem` style.

It provides toggles for `articletitle` (true by default) and `chaptertitle` (false be default), but not for `inproceedingstitle`. Happily we can patch things to make this work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{beziat_launay_typo_Metrans_2015,
  title = {A Comprehensive View of Goods Transport Systems. Typology and Analysis of Delivery Tours in the Paris Region},
  author = {Beziat, Adrien and Launay, Pierre and Toilier, Florence},
  booktitle = {6th Metrans International Urban Freight Conference},
  address = {Long Beach, CA, USA},
  year = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=chem-biochem]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% create a new toggle to control printing of titles in inproceedings entry
% type (this is optional, you could just make it always print; but fits the
% default behaviour of the style better)
\newtoggle{bbx:inproceedingstitle}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{inproceedingstitle}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:inproceedingstitle}{#1}%
}
% pathch inproceedings driver to print title if the inproceedingstitle toggle
% is true
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
   \newunit
   \iftoggle{bbx:inproceedingstitle}
     {\usebibmacro{title}}
     {}}
  {}
  {}
% set the inproceedingstitle toggle to true
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{inproceedingstitle=true}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]